# count string frequency in a column in R and keep other column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like

```
 a = c("sample1", "asd")
 b = c("sample2" ,"poua")
 c = c("sample3", "asd")

 dat <- rbind(a,b,c)
```

I would like to count column2 string frequencies, and keep column1 name in list/ragged array of counts. i.e. have it look like

```
 asd    sample1     sample3
 poua   sample2
```

I know table counts frequency, but I wasnt able to get it to keep names, so I would really really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tapply`:

```
tapply(dat[,1], dat[,2], as.vector)

$asd
[1] "sample1" "sample3"

$poua
[1] "sample2"
```

EDIT: If your rownames matter, you can use `identity` as the function:

```
tapply(dat[,1], dat[,2], identity)

$asd
        a         c 
"sample1" "sample3" 

$poua
        b 
"sample2"
```